# Genymotion - accessing Rails server on host machine?

Tags: android, ruby-on-rails

OK, so I got Genymotion working beautifully and I can already see how quickly this will speed up Android development longer term. However, I am having one problem currently that is keeping me from moving forward. I am unable to access a Rails server on my host machine from the Genymotion VM, and it appears to be a port issue of some kind. The reason I say that is because I can open a browser in my Nexus 4 VM, and navigate to

```
http://192.168.1.114
```

with no problem (my WampServer page shows up fine), but if I try to go to

```
http://192.168.1.114:3000
```

(where my rails server is running, and I can access it fine from a host browser) I get a net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT and see no activity in my rails log either. I've tried going through settings on the Android VM, the VirtualBox Manager, Genymotion itself, etc. to no avail, as well as turning off all firewalls completely.

Right now the VirtualBox Network is configured as

Adapter 1 - Host-only adapter

Adapter 2 - NAT

Any thoughts what might be causing this?

Answer (score 0):

Okay,

its a Vb setting

cheat in your OS host file se that Ip to domain name for example:

192.168.1.114:3000 myrailserver.my.me

and that should work just fine

Comment: Thanks Fred, I'll give it a shot. Are you talking about the hosts file for the host (a Win7 machine in my case) or the hosts file for the Android VM itself?

Comment: win7 host file as the VM in this case VB has a shared nat remember?So your change will flow through to the VM guest

Comment: I didn't have any luck with this unfortunately. I may have been doing something wrong for sure. Anyways, instead of the 192.168.1.114 address I ended up using 10.0.3.2, which did not have the same port 3000 problem, so I was able to connect to my rails server. No idea why!